# Where can I find documentation on the methods I can call on the base String class Google's Scripting language

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am writing some logic to manipulate a Google Spreadsheet using Google Script. I want to call some of the methods on String value I have in a cell. Specifically I am looking to replace all ' with '' in all strings. I am however unable to find out what methods I can call on the base String class. All more complex classes are documented, but can't seem to locate documentation for these base classes (String etc) - do they support replaceAll() for example.

Answer (score 1):

Google Script is based on Javascript, therefore any string has javascript methods, including your replace method. 
To list all the Javascript string specific methods:

1. charAt()
2. charCodeAt()
3. concat()
4. fromCharCode()
5. indexOf()
6. lastIndexOf()
7. localeCompare()
8. match()
9. **replace()** - Searches for a match between a substring (or regular expression) and a string, and replaces the matched substring with a new substring
10. search()
11. slice()
12. split()
13. substr()
14. substring()
15. toLocaleLowerCase()
16. toLocaleUpperCase()
17. toLowerCase()
18. toString()
19. toUpperCase()
20. trim()
21. valueOf()

More details, [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp)